google APIのOAuth2.0認証において、期限が切れたリフレッシュトークンを簡単に更新したい
google APIのOAuth2.0認証において、期限が切れたリフレッシュトークンをgoogleアカウントのログインなしに更新したいです。
現在公開ステータスがテストになっており、リフレッシュトークンの期限が7日間です。まだデプロイ等を行うのは先なので半年以上はテストのままになっています。
期限がきれたら毎回クライアントIDを削除して、認証手順を踏まえて再作成し、リフレッシュトークンを再発行しております。
認証手順にてgoogleアカウントでログインするのが時間がかかってしまっているので、それ以外の方法でリフレッシュトークンの再発行や更新をすることはできないのでしょうか？


google APIのOAuth2.0認証において、期限が切れたリフレッシュトークンをgoogleアカウントのログインなしに更新したいです。

これは、実現できません。リフレッシュ トークンの取得には、認証が必要になります。

期限がきれたら毎回クライアントIDを削除して、認証手順を踏まえて再作成し、リフレッシュトークンを再発行しております。

Client ID を変更する必要はないかと思いますが、一連の認証フローを実行する必要があります。
このあたりの処理は、Google API Client Library を使用することで、コードを削減できます。

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library?hl=ja

もしくは、バッチのような対話を伴わないサーバーサイドでの処理であれば、サービス アカウント を使用した認証を利用できます。

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?hl=ja

サービス アカウントを利用する場合は、秘密キーをセキュアに管理する必要がでてきますので、この点、十分に注意ください。

ありがとうございます！大変よくわかりました。Google API Client Libraryについて導入できるか検討してみます！
